# hide() doesn't work on my website, while it works fine on jfiddle

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, hide

I have a problem. I have copied exactly the same code as I have on my page and it works fine on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/7Gv47/3/). This code doesn't work when I paste it to html/css/js. Is there any reason that happens? what is wrong with the code?
I'm sure it's something simple, but I just can't figure it out. Thank you very much for your help in advance. 
BTW: here is a [source code](http://leedscity.captive-portal.com/generic/11111menu.html) if you need one. Need to wait 4 seconds as it will slide down. The X button should hide the wholde div, but it doesn't. that's the issue.

the code is here:

```
     <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="cookies">
            <p>Leed City Wifi uses cookies. By continuing to browse the site you are agreeing to use our cookies: </p>
            <a href="terms-cookies.html">Find out more</a>
            <a href="#" id="close" > <img src="http://content.captive-portal.com/cookies/_images/close.png"/></a>
        </div>        
</div>
```

and jquery here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#wrapper').hide();
function delay() {
    $('#wrapper').slideDown(500);
}
setTimeout(delay, 500);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#cookies').hide();
function delay() {
    $('#cookies').slideDown(200);
}
setTimeout(delay, 4000);
});


$("#close").click(function() {
 $("#cookies").slideUp(function() {
     window.location.href = "#";
     });
 });
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/7Gv47/3/).
Thank you for your time in advance

Comment: Do you have jquery included in your `<head>`?

Comment: @ATOzTOA yes, I do have. this jquery also makes an animate down animation (which works fine)

Comment: The way you use it... wouldnt it be better to set your CSS to display: none instead of using .hide() ?

Comment: sorted below :) but thank you very much for all your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your delay.js file to this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper').hide();
    $('#cookies').hide();

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#wrapper').slideDown(500);
    }, 500);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#cookies').slideDown(200);
    }, 4000);

    $("#close").click(function() {
        $("#cookies").slideUp(function() {
            window.location.href = "#";
        });
    });
});
```

I've put it all in one `document.ready` block, rather than multiple ones, put the functions directly into the timeout calls, and fixed a syntax error with the close click handler (you were missing some closing parenthesis).

Also, the close click handler needed to be assigned during `document.ready`, which it previously wasn't.  That's why it worked on jsFiddle, because that used onLoad by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#wrapper').hide();

    function delay1() {
        $('#wrapper').slideDown(500);
    }

    setTimeout(delay1, 500);

    $('#cookies').hide();

    function delay2() {
        $('#cookies').slideDown(200);
    }

    setTimeout(delay2, 4000);

    $("#close").click(function() {
        $("#cookies").slideUp(function() {
            window.location.href = "#";
        });
    });
});
```